# Prevent modal content open by default

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog

How to make the content inside not open before it was clicked? Whenever I make modal or dropdown list menu, it always, by default, opens the content before it was clicked. Why?

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('modal-wrap');
var open = document.getElementById('modal-open');
var close = document.getElementById('modal-close');


open.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};


close.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.modal-wrap {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    opacity: 40%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

.modal-close {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-close:hover,
.modal-close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button id="modal-open">Open</button>
      <div id="modal-wrap" class="modal-wrap">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <button class="modal-close" id="modal-close">Close</button>
          <p>Edit the data </p>
              <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input id="name" placeholder="Input your Name"> 
              </div>
  
        </div> 

      </div>
```

and also it runs well (as expected) in the snippet or in the JS Bin. But why does its appearance become different by default when am I running it on my (project) localhost? [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP6bh.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

All I can think about is maybe your JavaScript file is not linked properly?